# Android: Adding more than one Bundle to a new activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass in two separate pieces of information to a new activity in my Android application. 
I currently have this:

```
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); // student id
dataBundle.putInt("id", 0);// lesson id
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.LessonNotes.class);
intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

I then have the code accessing this information. However, adding the second bundle overrides the first one.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Bundle studentId = getIntent().getExtras();
Log.d("LessonID: ", String.valueOf(extras));
Log.d("StudentID: ", String.valueOf(studentId));
```

I need to have the information passed in separately as I need to check if one of them is null.

Can what i'm asking be done? Any ideas as to how to do this? Or another way to do this? (parsing maybe?)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use `putExtra("bundle1", bundle1)` and `putExtra("bundle2", bundle2)`  and then use `getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle1");` and `getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle2");` to retrieve both

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're over thinking this.  You can put a ton of information in 1 bundle.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("studentid", "Student0983");
bundle.putInt("lessonid", 0);
bundle.putString("moreinfo", "needed some extra data on that student");
bundle.putInt("studentincome", 4250);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.LessonNotes.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now to get that data in the new activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Log.d("studentid: ", bundle.getString("studentid"));
Log.d("lessonid: ", bundle.getInt("lessonid"));
Log.d("moreinfo: ", bundle.getString("moreinfo"));
Log.d("studentincome: ", bundle.getInt("studentincome"));
```

Comment: Xjasz has it, you can put all of the information on a single bundle using multiple .putxxx method calls.  If you want to group the information into logical pieces bigger than a single int or string, you can also create a class and have it implement parcelable.